# Prove that $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{n^2} + ... + \frac{n}{n^2}$ is Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

*My Solution*:

$|a_{n+k} - a_n| = |\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}*(1+2+...+n+k) - \frac{1}{n^2}*(1+2+...+n)|=$

$= |\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}* (1+2+...+n) + \frac{n+1}{(n+k)^2} + ... + \frac{n+k}{(n+k)^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}*(1+2+...+n) |= $

$= |(1+2+...+n)(\frac{1}{(n+k)^2} - \frac{1}{n^2})  + \frac{n+1+n+2+...+n+k}{(n+k)^2}| \le $

$\le |\frac{kn+1+2+..+k}{(n+k)^2}| \le \frac{kn+k^2}{(n+k)^2} = ... = \frac{k}{n} + 1$

Due to the fact that for a random $k$ the quantity $\frac{k}{n}$ can not be small enough, the sequence is not Cauchy

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you made is this: showing that, for $n$ large enough and $k\in \mathbb N$, the quantity $|a_{n+k}-a_n|$ is bounded by something large is not enough to prove a sequence is not Cauchy. You must show that you *cannot bound it by something small*. Refer to ILoveMath's answer for a hint on how to do the problem.

Comment: I think that you answered my question ! Thank you for your support !

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Notice that

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n^2 + n }{2n^2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n} $$

Comment: Thank you for your hint.

Comment: I'm curious if I don't remember that $1+2+...+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $ how could I solve the problem. So, my question is: How could my solution be fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac12+\frac{1}{2n},\,|a_{n+k}-a_n|=\frac{k}{2n(n+k)}\lt\frac{1}{2n}.$$Yep, it's a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: No I didn't. I split the $\frac{1+2+...+n+k}{(n+k)^2}$ to  $\frac{1+2+...+n}{(n+k)^2} + \frac{n+1}{(n+k)^2} + ... + \frac{n+k}{(n+k)^2} $

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis Thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a hammer to crack a nut, this is a Riemann sum :
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} \rightarrow \int_0^1 t \mathrm{dt} = \frac{1}{2}$$